# Creating Const value using a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to achieve similar result to this code:

```
  const myResult = useMemo(
    () => {
      var arr = ["el1"]
      if(someCondition){
        arr.push( "el2", "el3")
      }
      return arr 
    }, [someCondition]
  )
```

but without using useMemo(), just simple const (it is simple so can be recomputed with every render and I want to maintain a code as simple as it's possible)

I was thinking about something like this

```
  const myResult = () => {
      var arr = ["el1"]
      if(someCondition){
        arr.push( "el2", "el3")
      }
      return arr
  }
```

but in that case array is a function returning array of strings, not array of strings it self.

I know I can do it like this

```
const myResult = someCondition ? ["el1", "el2", "el3"] : ["el1"]
```

but I don't like here that "el1" is duplicated in code...

Is it possible to achieve my goal or I overthink the problem?

Comment: If you just make your approach into a self-executing function ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)), it will act identically to the memo approach (in terms of output)

Comment: *Call* the function you've written: `const myResult = () => { /*...*/ }();` Note the `()` at the end. Or don't make it a function at all, just `const myResult = ["el"]; /*...code to optionally push the others...*/`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I believe you have to wrap arrow function in `()` before they are called, so it would be `const myResult = (() => { /*...*/ })()`

Comment: there are odd things to me while reading the question. You said _but in that case array is a function returning array of strings, not array of strings it self_ .. well actually `array` is never defined and probably you meant `return arr` instead. In that case the returned value would be the array you were looking for. As per the duplication of the `el1` you can define the array as containing only `el1` at first and in the else branch just `push` the other elements. Of course since `myResult` is defined as a function, you have to invoke it of course

Comment: @DBS - Thanks. My bad, you do need them with an arrow function (you don't with a traditional function *in that context* -- but I'd probably include the `()` even then). Don't know why I left them out.

Comment: `['el1', ...(someCondition ? ['el2', 'el3'] : [])]`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least four choices:

1. Add the `()` necessary to *call* the function you wrote to replace the `useMemo` call,

   or
2. Don't use a function wrapper at all (this is what I'd do)

   or
3. As [deceze suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77859388/creating-const-value-using-a-function/77859468#comment137260958_77859388) for this specific case, use spread notation to spread out either your `el2`, `el3` array or an empty one

   or
4. If your real use case requires temporary variables, etc., use an anonymous/standalone block rather than a function.

Here's #1:

```
const myResult = (() => {
    const arr = ["el1"];
    if (someCondition) {
        arr.push( "el2", "el3");
    }
    return arr;
})();
```

Here's #2 (which is what I'd do):

```
const myResult = ["el1"];
if (someCondition) {
    myResult.push( "el2", "el3");
}
```

Here's #3:

```
const myResult = ["el1", ...(someCondition ? ["el2", "el3"] : [])];
```

Here's #4 (only makes sense if you have temporary variables within the block):

```
const myResult = ["el1"];
{
    if (someCondition) {
        myResult.push( "el2", "el3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! #1 I think is most universal, but you're right - in that case more elegant would be #3
I just don't really understand #2 as I want myResult to be const so I won't be able to push there more value if someCondition is checked after declaration

Comment: @MatteoDelOmbra - You have a bit of a misunderstanding there: `const` **doesn't** make the array immutable (which is why #2 above works). All it does is prevent you from assigning a *different* array to `myResult`. All four of these options (and your original `useMemo` code) result in a mutable array.

Comment: yeah... I just read some about consts - now I know more. But still I think I'll go with #3 as for me it's a little bit unintuitive that js consts are mutable :D

Comment: @MatteoDelOmbra - :-) `const`s aren't mutable. The things they *point* to sometimes are. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Define the function outside of your component. Note that the function now receives `someCondition` as an argument:

```
const getMyResult = (someCondition) => {
  const arr = ["el1"]
  if (someCondition) arr.push("el2", "el3")
  return arr
}
```

Now call it inside your component, and pass `someCondition`:

```
const Comp = ({ someCondition }) => {
  const myResult = getMyResult(someCondition)
  //...
}
```